# Derivation showing phasor representation of $A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I recently posted in Electrical Engineering Stack and no body could give me an answer so I have come to the mathematicians. So in steady state AC circuit analysis we usually transform everything into the frequency domain by using the Fourier transform. For example, if I wanted the frequency domain representation of the voltage across an inductor, I would take the Fourier transform of the differential equation describing it.

$v(t)=L\ di(t)/dt$

$\mathcal{F}[v(t)=L\ di(t)/dt] \rightarrow V(\omega)=j\omega L\ I(\omega)$ where $j$ is the imaginary number.

So when you transform a AC circuit into the frequency domain you also transform the source.

$S(t) = A\ cos(\omega_0t+\phi)$

$\mathcal{F}[S(t)] \rightarrow A\ e^{j\phi}$

So I have not been able to find any proof that the Fourier transform of "Source" $S  =  A\ e^{j\phi}$. When I attempt to derive it by taking the Fourier transform of "Source" I end up with:

$\mathcal{F}[S] \rightarrow A\ \pi [e^{j\phi}\delta(\omega-\omega_0)+e^{-j\phi}\delta(\omega+\omega_0)]$

I next use the condition that $\omega = \omega_0$ since the frequency will be constant in the system.
This leaves me with:

$A\ \pi e^{j\phi}$

So I have a factor of $\pi$ that I do not know what to do with. I am not sure how we can simply say:

$\mathcal{F}[S] \rightarrow A\ e^{j\phi}$

When that is not what you get. Is their any obvious things I am missing? The answer I get looks very close so I feel like I am on the right track.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please refer to [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use MathJax. As far as your question goes, there is a saying my friend's adviser told him: "$\pi$ equals $2\pi$ equals $1$". You probably picked the wrong convention for the Fourier transform to end up with that factor.

Comment: @NinadMunshi What do you mean by "π equals 2π equals 1" and how does it translate to being able to set the magnitude A*PI of a complex number = just A?

Comment: It means exactly what I said. There are many different conventions for the Fourier Transform that are off by factors of $\pi$. It has nothing to do with complex numbers.

Comment: Use the angular frequency form of the Fourier transform on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional